# Load different views for different screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

How can I load a view, inside a tab bar in code? To determine what screen size I'm dealing I use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height`, but after, how do I load the view?
At the moment, I'm using two "modal segues" from the `First View Controller` and `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"3.5" sender:self];`, but when I do this, the view covers the tab bar.

[image: storyboard]

Comment: I'd suggest you to do everything in 4" and use AutoLayout.

Comment: But the views will have a slightly different content.

Comment: How do your first view controllers size themselves correctly for 3.5 or 4" devices? I would definitely try to use autolayout

Comment: but with autolayout I lost support for olders versions of iOS